# Is there a word for making a neologism by adding an "em" prefix to nouns or adjective?

Tags: prefixes, neologisms, verbing

I am a trusted critic of a friend's writing. I have noticed an (admittedly obnoxious) habit they have of "creating" new words by adding the "em" prefix to nouns or adjectives, like empurpled.

For example they will say things like "The boy stared, his eyes emgoldened by sun," or "The girls walked with empowdered faces." "The emspangled sky." "His embrightened smile."

The closest I've come to finding an answer on my own is the terms "verbing." I also know "em" is frequently used as an intensifier. I've taken to calling it "emverbing" but I wonder if there isn't a real term for this particular type of move.

This is pretty specific, so my broader question would be: is there a word which describes creating a neologism by affixing a prefix to a word that doesn't typically have one. I haven't been able to find any term.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A side note: “emgoldened” and “emspangled” are particularly eccentric because this prefix typically takes the form “en-“ before G or S. The form “em” is only regular before B or P (or I suppose before M, although I can’t think of any common example).

Comment: Is the word you're looking for "derivation"? Coincidentally, see [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/469970/191178) I really recently posted.

Comment: I'm not sure if embrighten counts as a neologism or not since it's in an actual dictionary, but either way, I'm using this as an excuse to say, "I am so sorry you have to deal with that." https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrighten

Comment: As long it is their work, and they are aware of the consequences, there is no need to feel that it is obnoxious, because they may go on from there to create something special. Or they might not, but they are friends, so enjoy!

Comment: No need to *embiggen the issue. (*em)Coined *em-* words are **not** neologisms but poor puns or just-for-funs. Only those in the dictionary are proper words.

Comment: Not sure what makes you think there is word for making a very specific and narrow subset of neologisms, if we don't even have a word for making neologisms, period.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Neologize is given in many dictionaries, at least the ones I've checked. M-W, Collins, American Heritage, Oxford Online Dictionaries, and Random House.

Answer (score 2):

As Laurel points out, the process of forming new words by appending prefixes and suffixes is called [*morphological derivation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(linguistics)). Not an arbitrary process, it follows certain idiomatic conventions, either phonetic or semantic, that assure that a new coinage looks, tastes, and feels like English. When it doesn’t, you can term it “illegal,” “nonidiomatic,” or, if it suits you, just plain wrong.

The first criterion is whether an affix is still productive, i. e., it is still used to form new words. *Pro-* and *anti-*, for instance, are highly productive; *be-* as in *bedraggled* or *bedazzled* is not. I suppose *ante* ‘before, prior to’ might be glued onto some Latin root to come up with a new word, but chances are good no one is going to say they need to make a phonecall **antebreakfast*.

You can at least assure your friend that [*em-* is still productive](https://www.etymonline.com/word/em-#etymonline_v_5760) in modern English. When commercial aviation became a thing in the 1920s, for instance, industry-specific terms were coined for getting on and off: thus *enplane/[emplane](https://www.etymonline.com/word/emplane#etymonline_v_50313)* and *deplane* were born.

The *emplane/enplane* variation brings up a phonetic rule for your friend’s favorite prefix: *em*- is really *en*- assimilated to a root beginning with a labial consonant, b, p, and sometimes m. That means it can never be attached to a root beginning with a vowel or any other consonant. This eliminates such attempts as **emgolden*. The rule would generate *engolden*:

> About the same time the royal palanquin stood at the palace portal, [*engoldened*](https://books.google.de/books?id=A2ZRDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&dq=engoldened&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzs6Hjr6HeAhXKPFAKHfoJAbcQ6AEILDAB), jewelled, and surmounted with a panache of green plumes. — Lew Wallace,  *The Fair God*, 2018 (orig.1873), 51.

Staying with colors, *empurpled* already exists:

> vnwares it [a knife] strooke into her snowie chest,
>   that litle drops *empurpled* her faire brest:  Edmund Spenser, *The Faerie Queen*, 1590. EEOB

Today, one also encounters the word in a metaphorical sense:

> Firbank's spoofing is altogether too silly, too [*empurpled*](https://books.google.de/books?id=WDVaAAAAMAAJ&q=empurpled&dq=empurpled&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjik8_MraHeAhUDmbQKHR-pC6U4ChDoAQhGMAc), too doting to sustain the mood of correction essential to satire. — Robert F. Kiernan, *Frivolity Unbound: Six Masters of the Camp Novel*, 1990.

[*Purple prose*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/purple_prose#English) is flowery, extravagant writing, which means if you use a word such as *empurple*, you’re more than halfway there — as in this early 20th century poem about the San Gabriel Mountains of California:

> Where range upon range the Sierra lies dreaming a-swim
>    In the stillness of April, the warm golden splendor of light,
>   [*Enrosed and emblued*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31210003724950;view=2up;seq=226;skin=mobile) and snow-summitted height after height, 
>   Bathed in silence and color… *Sunset Magazine* 16/4 (Feb. 1906)

As far as I can tell, neither *enrose* nor *emblue* has an entry in any dictionary: they are [*nonce words*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word) created just for this poem. But because they follow the conventions of coining such words, any reader would understand them. Whether this is a literary success is up to the reader to decide.

You may have noticed these *en*- color words occur in quite formal registers — poetry of varied quality or a well crafted sentence in a novel — and all breathe the air of earlier centuries. Excellent writers might get away with resurrecting them or coining new ones; merely good writers might be better advised to avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on information I've learned from reading online sources.

There was a similar question to this not long ago about attaching the prefix "a-" to a word.

[What is the grammatical name of prefixing a word by "A"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/466976/what-is-the-grammatical-name-of-prefixing-a-word-by-a/467014#467014)

That question is more broad than yours because the prefix/morpheme 'a-' has more functions and separate origins than what you're talking about, specifically adding the prefixal morpheme of "em-" to a word.

First of all, to answer your broad question:

> is there a word which describes
>   creating a neologism by affixing a prefix to a word that doesn't
>   typically have one.

I can't think of a term more specific than "prefixation" or "verbification".

**ABOUT THE PREFIX/MORPHEME EN- / EM-**

More specifically, to address your question about adding the "em-" prefix to a word, I think most people understand what this morpheme means.

em-

> word-forming element meaning "put in or into, bring to a certain
>   state," ...

usually when followed by:

> labial stop (-b-, -p-, and often -m-)

and:

> Also a living prefix in English used to form verbs from adjectives and
>   nouns (embitter, embody)

Source: [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/em-#etymonline_v_5760)

The prefix morphemes "en-" and "em-" are a French adoption or shift from Latin "in-" and "im-". In French this change is more consistent. However English tended to adopt both the French forms and the Latin forms (see [entry for "in-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/in-#etymonline_v_6284)). That's why even today we have "empanel/impanel", "imbed/embed" and "ensure/insure". Older spellings in English showing this include "imbalm", "impower", "imbody", and "incumber".

***ON CREATING VERBS FROM NON-VERBS***

The Wikipedia article on [Conversion (word formation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_(word_formation)#Verbing) talks about "verbification". If the Wikipedia article is accurate, then there is a distinction between "to verb" and "to verbify".

- "To verb" means using a non-verb as a verb without changing or adding to word.
- To "verbify" means changing a non-verb to use it as a verb with the adding an affix.

So words such as you've given seem to be cases of verbifying, not verbing. I'm not sure if this is a widely held distinction.

So the phenomenon that you're talking about seems to be "verbifying", particularly by "prefixation". However I don't know a word that covers both. Such a word would likely be the answer to your question.

Also your examples of "emverbing", "emgoldened" and "emspangled" go against the general trend of using "in-/im-/en-/em-" before certain letters, generally rules based on phonological considerations.

Comment: See my comment at OP.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, it seems you're right. The un- English prefix doesn't seem to care what sound follows: unbuckle, unbeatable, unbridle, unpack, unplug, unpaid. Very different prefix/morpheme. One exception I found was enplane, also spelt emplane, but they seem to be so rare it's not even worth mentioning. Thanks for the correction, and the lesson. I'll remove that final part of my answer.

Comment: @Kris Are you saying we shouldn't coin new words that begin with em- ? I found that "embrittle" is relatively new, 1900 - 1905, but is found in dictionaries now (ie., "real words"). The Simpsons has had an enormous impact on our language, and is most likely the reason why "meh" is in our dictionaries. "embiggen" is actually found in official dictionaries, Collins, Merriam-Webster, Oxford Living Dictionaries. I don't see why this should be discouraged in any way. I'm sure the first people using any newly coined word were seen as silly or eccentric until it slowly became accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure why the discussion of *en-* changing to *em-* before labials is restricted to stops. Although not a verb formed from a noun, *emphasise*  exists - and *ph* is a fricative. As does [emforth](http://www.websters1913.com/words/Emforth), and [emvowel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emvowel). I can't find any examples, but *\*emwiden*  sounds as valid as *embiggen* and *\*enwiden* doesn't sound good to me.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: The word *emphasize* comes from Greek; Greek "ph" is thought to have originally been pronounced as an aspirated bilabial plosive, although it changed to a fricative fairly early on (exactly how early is disputed/unclear). *Emforth* doesn't seem to have the prefix *em-*. I have only seen *emvowel* as a sub-unit of the jocular word *disemvowel(ed)* which is clearly modeled after *disembowel(ed).*

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I have posted a new question for information about details on the use of en- vs em-: [The use of “en-” vs “em-” as a prefix](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/470171/the-use-of-en-vs-em-as-a-prefix)

Comment: @sumelic I was looking only for examples of the phonology that might influence wordsmiths. A further problem is that there are examples in English where an *n* is written but an /m/ pronounced. I shall read the new question with interest.